# How to make an example like > Array > {} > name: {}

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

## What I want to achieve

Because this is what I return.

```json
[
  {
    "question": {
      "id": 12,
      "question": "Wat is bestaan?",
      "form_versionnumber": "1",
      "form_name": "testv2"
    }
  },
  {
    "question": {
      "id": 13,
      "question": "Is de aarde plat?",
      "form_versionnumber": "1",
      "form_name": "testv2"
    }
  },
  {
    "question": {
      "id": 14,
      "question": "Hoeveel dimensies bestaan er?",
      "form_versionnumber": "1",
      "form_name": "testv2"
    }
  }
]
```

## What I have now

I am using swagger for docs and I made a definition to make an example.
But I can't get it the same.
And its important because its an example

This is what I have now:

```json
"questionModel": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "id": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "question": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "form_versionnumber": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "form_name": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        }
    },
"questions": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": {

                "type": "objects",
                "$ref": "#/definitions/questionModel"
            }
        }
    }
```

## What my definition creates

```json
[
  {
    "additionalProp1": {
      "id": 0,
      "question": "string",
      "form_versionnumber": 0,
      "form_name": "string"
    },
    "additionalProp2": {
      "id": 0,
      "question": "string",
      "form_versionnumber": 0,
      "form_name": "string"
    },
    "additionalProp3": {
      "id": 0,
      "question": "string",
      "form_versionnumber": 0,
      "form_name": "string"
    }
  }
]
```

### Problem

Each prop is not in its own curly braces but instead in 1.
I don't know how to explain better or how to fix it either.

Comment: It's technically generating the right thing. Are you using Java for the service or some other language?

Comment: I am using javascript. If you look closely each prop needs to be in his own { }.
They are now in just 1.